# Best way to make a project with post-build script work on MonoDevelop and Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, linux, visual-studio, cross-platform, monodevelop

I have an open source project in which I'm trying to allow development on both MonoDevelop(including *nix) and Visual Studio. One of my recently discovered requirements is I need to copy an outputted file from one directory to another(relative path).

Windows however has the `copy` command, while *nix has the `cp` command. What is the best way to get this to work on both platforms and resolve this difference of commands?

Comment: If you are really adamant about having one script for all, you might want to have a look into cygwin, which provides "a Linux look and feel environment for Windows." see more here: http://www.cygwin.com/

Comment: @nieve I have that installed, I just didn't want to force everyone who wants to compile my project on Windows to install it

Comment: You can add a sort of an installation script (something like rake/make) to set up the environment of the other developers, which will decide post-build script will be used according to the OS. If you look at how to build MonoDevelop, you'll see they're using different mechanisms altogether for different environments/OS.

Comment: @Earlz Did you ever find a solution here? I literally have one DLL to copy... Forcing everyone to install cygwin just for a copy command is pretty overkill

Comment: @Earlz The best I came up with was to make an alias for xcopy on Linux for 'cp -r' 
As far as I can tell, xcopy isn't anything my standard linux distro picks up, and I definitely don't have anything similar installed on Ubuntu... Soooo, yeah.

Answer (score 22):

Where possible, if you can lean on built-in MSBuild tasks rather than custom shell scripting, the behavior will generally work on xbuild (and hence MonoDevelop?) without any changes, so no need for platform-specific *proj hacks.

eg:

```
 <Target Name="AfterBuild">
          <Copy SourceFiles="foo.txt" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)" />
 </Target>
```

This is from the mono docs:
http://www.mono-project.com/archived/porting_msbuild_projects_to_xbuild/#prepostbuildevents

Answer (score 18):

You can use the `$OS` variable to have different post build events depending on the environment. To do this, you must edit the csproj by hand, like:

```
<PostBuildEvent Condition="'$(OS)' == 'Windows_NT' ">
    dir
</PostBuildEvent>
<PostBuildEvent Condition="'$(OS)' != 'Windows_NT'">
    ls
</PostBuildEvent>
```

Comment: No Visual Studio integration for this

Comment: @DanielDäschle - what do you mean by that? Does it make this answer not useful somehow?

Comment: i can't remeber what i meant. Just ignore it :D

Answer (score 1):

You could write the post build script in a language like Python. Or you could require other developers to install GnuWin32 CoreUtils as an option to installing CygWin. CoreUtils includes cp. Then you can just unconditionally use cp.